# PHPUnit and Custom Types

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

This is how my bundle main file is

```
<?php

namespace Foo\FooBundle;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class FooBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container) 
    {
        parent::build($container);
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        Type::addType('custom_date', 'Foo\FooBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\CustomDate');
        $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('custom_date','custom_date');
     }
}
```

So as you might night I have a custom type that I have registered during `boot()` operation of my bundle.

Now, during my test(s) I ran through some problems. Some test needs to use static functions `setUpBeforeClass()` and `tearDownAfterClass()` because I need `EntityManager` and `Container`. Below my functions (commons to more than one test class)

```
public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();
    self::$em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager()
    ;
}

public static function tearDownAfterClass()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    self::$em->close();
}
```

Now, if I run more than one test class that use `static::$kernel->boot();` some test fails due to DBAL exceptions claming that `custom_date` type is already registered.

This is pretty strange to me as `parent::tearDown();` function is

```
/**
 * Shuts the kernel down if it was used in the test.
 */
protected function tearDown()
{
    if (null !== static::$kernel) {
        static::$kernel->shutdown();
    }
}
```

and `static::$kernel->shutdown();` is

```
public function shutdown()
{
    if (false === $this->booted) {
        return;
    }

    $this->booted = false;

    foreach ($this->getBundles() as $bundle) {
        $bundle->shutdown();
        $bundle->setContainer(null);
    }

    $this->container = null;
}
```

So, to me, if bundle is shutted down, teorically, even his custom types should be unregistered. It seems they don't.

---

### My solution

I've modified `boot()` function in order to check if type is already registered

```
public function boot()
{
    if (false === Type::hasType('custom_date')) {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        Type::addType('custom_date', 'Foo\FooBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\CustomDate');
        $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('custom_date','custom_date');
}
```

}

---

### Question(s)

1. Do anyone know why DBAL type isn't unregistered when bundle is shoutted down?
2. Is my solution safe? Is the only solution or do you know others?

Comment: excuseme, why you don't refine the custom type in the `config.yml` section as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types ?

Comment: @jack i've just followed symfony2 cookbook, wasn't aware of that possibility. My solution is still a working one yet so questions are still valids :)

Comment: of course, onyl a curiosity